# Tabulator scrollToRow not working and no errors shown

Tags: javascript, scroll, svelte, tabulator

When the page loads, no scrolling is done. There are no errors too.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Is there another way to go to the desired row? I don't need the scrolling animation, just to get to the row.

```
$: if (tableElement && data && columns) {
    table = new Tabulator(tableElement, {
        height: "100%",
        layout: "fitData",
        data: data,
        cellVertAlign: "middle",
        resizableColumns: "header",
        groupStartOpen: true,
        groupToggleElement: "header",
        columnHeaderSortMulti: true,
        columnCalcs: "both",
        tooltipsHeader: true,
        virtualDomBuffer: 50000, // I read in another post to increase this, but it does nothing
        groupHeader: (value, count, data, group) => {
            return `
                ${value}
                <span style="color:#d00; margin-left:10px;">
                    ${count}
                </span>
            `;
        },
        columns: columns,
    });
}

$: if (table && $scrollToRecordId) {
    console.log("SCROLLING");

    table
        .scrollToRow($scrollToRecordId, "top", true)
        .then(() => {
            console.log("done");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Is this svelte or sveltekit? If sveltekit, you might need to disable the built in scrollhandling for yours to work: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-navigation-disablescrollhandling

Comment: This is just svelte. Anything for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is using `tick`.

```
import { tick } from "svelte";

$: if (table && $scrollToRecordId) {
    scrollTable();
}

async function scrollTable() {
    await tick();
    table.scrollToRow($scrollToRecordId, "top", true);
}
```

If you are getting a `no matching row` error, use this:

```js
table.on("tableBuilt", () => {
    if ($scrollToSku) {
        table.scrollToRow($scrollToSku, "top", true);
        $scrollToSku = null;
    }
});
```